# How to use multiple Or Operator in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to make a program which uses multiple `OR` operator in If statement..

```
 If aryTextFile(i) = "and" Or "but" Or "or" Or "nor" Or "for" Or "yet " Or "so" Then
                TextBox2.Text = aryTextFile(i) & " is a Coordinating Conjunctions"
```

But this gives out the error

```
Conversion from string "but" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.
```

I need help to make multiple or operator to work or even if i could replace if statement :P

Any help appreciated.

P.S - Beginner in programming !

Comment: for lots of comparisons of 1 thing against other things you can also consider using a `Select Case` expression (`switch` in C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use OrElse instead of Or (to not evaluate every instance, if the first is a match, it wont evaluate the rest of the expressions as it is not necessary)

And you have to do it like this:

```
If aryTextFile(i) = "and" OrElse aryTextFile(i) = "but" OrElse aryTextFile(i) = "or" Then
```

The string by itself is not a boolean expression

It expects "boolean expresson" OrElse "another boolean expression"

Comment: adding orElse gives me the same Boolean error.. and i worried adding multiple or statement will make the program bigger... can i replace the complete if statement?

Comment: I edited the answer, adding the orelse is only a small optimisation to how your code will evaluate the expression (stops at the first match, since the rest dont matter since "true or false = true"). The actual answer is you have to repeat the value you are comparing between each statement (edited the answer).